# Find module name by import C++

Tags: c++, winapi, dll, import

I want to find the name of an import during compile time.

So if I have `MessageBoxA`, I want to find the name of the module it is in, which in this case is `user32.dll`.

Is there any way I can do this at compile time (before running the executable)?

`MessageBoxA()` is just an example. I would like to be able to find the name of the module of any imported function, such as `OpenProcess()` or `ReadProcessMemory()`, all during compile time without manually specifying it.

I was thinking of finding the address and manually searching exports for each DLL until I find it, however I would prefer a more efficient way.

Comment: It's specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messageboxa)

Comment: Documentation is tor the weak. Real men program by trial and error and find themselves selling coffee instead of writing code. Funny how that turns out.

Comment: Damn, I guess I've been doing this whole coding thing wrong then.. lol @user4581301

Comment: I know it is specified in the documentation however I want to get it dynamically for every function and for example print the module name, I don't want to hardcode it unless I have to.

Comment: You find this before compile time from the documentation. Then you make sure you link your program with user32.lib when you build it.

Comment: Without dedicated tooling you cannot determine this information at compile time. Powerful as `consteval` may be, reading data from files is not among the supported features. Though it's questionable, why you are asking for `MessageBoxA`. No one in their right mind would want to start with technical debt from the get go. `MessageBoxW`, on the other hand, now that would be a totally different story.

Comment: Note for everyone asking me to use documentation, I don't want this for linking it, I want to make a class to import functions manually and instead of manually hardcoding "user32.dll" etc for every import that is from user32 and "kernelbase.dll" for every import that is from kernelbase, I would like to be able to automatically determine which module it is from, so if someone passes ReadProcessMemory for example it will return "kernel32.dll".

Comment: Then open up the dlls and find the symbols yourself. There are plenty of PE libraries to read the DLLs.

Comment: You cannot do what you are asking for. I'd post this as an answer, although *"You cannot do this"* answers tend to attract sentiment votes (*"I don't like this"*) rather than receiving votes that act as an indicator of correctness.

Comment: There is no way to do this at compile time. The *compiler* has no concept of DLLs or imports, that is the job of the *linker* to figure out. The *compiler* simply takes note/reference of a declared function that is being called in code, then the *linker* resolves that reference to an implementation, whether that is in the program's code, a static library, a DLL, etc